# Scipy's sparse eigsh() for small eigenvalues

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to write a spectral clustering algorithm using NumPy/SciPy for larger (but still tractable) systems, making use of SciPy's sparse linear algebra library. Unfortunately, I'm running into stability issues with [eigsh()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh).

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg as SLA
import sklearn.utils.graph as graph

W = self._sparse_rbf_kernel(self.X_, self.datashape)
D = scipy.sparse.csc_matrix(np.diag(np.array(W.sum(axis = 0))[0]))
L = graph.graph_laplacian(W) # D - W
vals, vects = SLA.eigsh(L, k = self.k, M = D, which = 'SM', sigma = 0, maxiter = 1000)
```

The `sklearn` library refers to the scikit-learn package, specifically [this method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/graph.py#L132) for calculating a graph laplacian from a sparse SciPy matrix.

`_sparse_rbf_kernel` is a method I wrote to compute pairwise affinities of the data points. It operates by creating a sparse affinity matrix from image data, specifically by only computing pairwise affinities for the 8-neighborhoods around each pixel (instead of pairwise for all pixels with scikit-learn's `rbf_kernel` method, which for the record doesn't fix this either).

Since the laplacian is unnormalized, I'm looking for the smallest eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the system. I understand that [ARPACK is ill-suited for finding small eigenvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082782/computing-n-smallest-eigenvalues-of-sparse-matrix-in-python), but I'm trying to use shift-invert to find these values and am still not having much success.

With the above arguments (specifically, `sigma = 0`), I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Factor is exactly singular

With `sigma = 0.001`, I get a different error:

> scipy.sparse.linalg.eigen.arpack.arpack.ArpackNoConvergence: ARPACK error -1: No convergence (1001 iterations, 0/5 eigenvectors converged)

I've tried all three different values for `mode` with the same result. **Any suggestions for using the SciPy sparse library for finding small eigenvalues of a large system?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `which='LM'`: in the shift-invert mode, this parameter refers to the transformed eigenvalues. (As explained in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh).)

Comment: Right, but the problem is I want the smallest eigenvalues and their associated eigenvectors, not the largest. The documentation explains that if small eigenvalues are desired, shift-invert mode should be used to improve performance, which is what I was trying to do by using `sigma`, to no avail.

Comment: The above should give you exactly what you want. Note: with sigma=0, the transformed eigenvalues are w'=1/(w-sigma)=1/w. Therefore, with `which='LM'` you get the eigenvalues with large **w'**, or in other words, the smallest eigenvalues of the original problem. If you use the shift-invert mode, you need to adjust also the `which` parameter accordingly.

Comment: Just wanted to say this was extremely helpful